# Random selection between 2 or more ranges

Tags: ruby, random

I'm trying to make a random number generator which will pick more "evenly" between 3 and 4 digit ranges. If I just do:

```
result = rand(100..9999)
```

I'm well aware that in the majority of cases, a 4 digit number will be selected. I want to give 3-digit numbers more chance of being selected, so I did this:

```
rand_3_digit_num = (100..999)
rand_4_digit_num = (1000..9999)

rand([rand_3_digit_num, rand_4_digit_num].sample)
```

Is there any other approach to do this? My goal is to just give 3-digit numbers bigger chance of being selected than with an ordinary rand. This problem gets even worse if I introduce 5-digit or 6-digit numbers, the chance of 3-digit or 4-digit numbers to get selected quickly diminishes.

Comment: Your code is actually the best answer. It is short, clear and it works fine.

Comment: Also, why do you want to do this? It will be fair to ranges but it will be unfair to the elements. 101 will appear 10 times as much as 1001 for example.

Answer (score 2):

Brute solution:

```
list = (100..999).to_a*10 + (1000..9999).to_a
=> [100, ..., 9999]
list.size
=> 18000
list.count { |e| e < 1000 }
=> 9000
list.count { |e| 999 < e && e < 10000 }
=> 9000
```

Now `list.sample` should give equal probabilities of 3- and 4-digits numbers.

Comment: It is equivalent to the OP proposed solution, but it is much slower.

Comment: You're right, I just didn't quite get OP's solution at first. My code is at least 400 slower on my machine. Anyway, in absolute numbers difference is not that noticeably, and also this approach gives more flexibility.

Comment: Also, it is slower only for the first time. Second and other calls are up to 2 times faster (again, on my machine) because an array is already exists and we need to call only one sample() against sample() + rand().

Comment: Interesting. What about memory consumption? :) What about when ranges don't have common divisors? Do you multiply each array by the length of the other one?

Comment: Well, I don't argue about that there are restrictions. This is just simplest answer that solves this particular problem, not some silver bullet :)

Answer (score 1):

First specify a probability distribution over ranges, say:

```
range_prob = { (100..999)     => 0.2,
               (1000..9999)   => 0.5,
               (10000..43562) => 0.3 }
```

Given these probabilities, a range can be selected at random thusly:

```
def select_random_range(range_prob)
  rnd_cum_prob = rand
  cum_prob = 0.0
  range_prob.each_with_object({}) do |(rng, prob),h|
    cum_prob += prob
    h[rng] = cum_prob
  end.find { |rng, cum_prob| rnd_cum_prob <= cum_prob }.first
end
```

What I have done here is construct a cumulative distribution function ("cdf") from the discrete probability density function ("pdf") `range_prob`. (See the graph below.) To obtain a random variate we generate a pseudo-random number between zero and one, plot that on the vertical axis, determine where a horizontal line intersects the cdf and select the associated value on the horizontal axis.

[image: cdf]

For `range_prob` above,

```
select_random_range(range_prob)      #=> 10000..43562 
select_random_range(range_prob)      #=> 100..999
select_random_range(range_prob)      #=> 1000..9999
select_random_range(range_prob)      #=> 100..999
select_random_range(range_prob)      #=> 10000..43562
```

Selecting a random value in a random range is small additional step.

```
rand select_random_range(range_prob) #=> 6467 
rand select_random_range(range_prob) #=> 16689 
rand select_random_range(range_prob) #=> 2282 
rand select_random_range(range_prob) #=> 1317 
rand select_random_range(range_prob) #=> 9015
```

See [Kernel#rand](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-rand).

Comment: Nice, and interesting if the OP wants more control. `rnd_cum_prob` could be picked between 0 and the sum of probabilities (in case they don't add to 1), and you could cache your cdf.

Comment: @Eric, yes caching would make sense (e.g., compute `@cdf` before any random variates are generated). I would be inclined to raise an exception if the probabilities didn't sum to 1.0.

Comment: Float comparison is tricky. I'd use weights and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea is good. What you want to achieve is find the uniformly random `N`, where `N` represents number of digits in the number, then find the  random number of length `N`.

You could split that in two functions:

```
randomSelection(lengths):
  K = A random number from the array lengths
  return randomNumberForLength(K)

randomNumberForLength(K):
  lower_bound = 10^K
  upper_bound = 10^(K+1) - 1
  return rand(lower_bound, upper_bound)
```

If you wanted to find a random number between `100 - 9999` giving equal probability to both 2-length and 3-length numbers, you can just call `randomSelection([2,3])`

Comment: Which language is that supposed to be exactly? It's not exactly Python and surely not Ruby. `10^5` is `15` (10 XOR 5) by the way. You want `10**k`.

Comment: This is just a pseudo-code. `10^15` represents power 10 to the 15th. Implementation is different depending on the language, but yeah, you are right, if it was python that would be `10**k`

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on how you want to bias the results. For example, if you want an even chance that you'll get a three or four digit number, you can use something as simple as (pseudo-code):

```
def getRand():
    if rand(0, 1) == 0:        // assume inclusive both ends.
        return rand(100, 999)
    return rand(1000, 9999)
```

Although the fact that you're calling `rand` twice may stuff up distributions for truly random requirements, it's probably good enough for most purposes.

To do it in a *single* call which is therefore likely to preserve distribution, you can just map values:

```
def getRand():
    num = rand(1000, 18999)
    if num > 9999:
        num = (num - 10000) % 900 + 100
```

This would generate two equal-sized groups, `1000-9999` and `10000-18999` and would map the values in the upper group to become `100-999` (hence equally likely to get a three- or four-digit number):

```
10000 - 10899  ->  100 - 999
10900 - 11799  ->  100 - 999
11800 - 12699  ->  100 - 999
12700 - 13599  ->  100 - 999
13600 - 14499  ->  100 - 999
14500 - 15399  ->  100 - 999
15400 - 16299  ->  100 - 999
16300 - 17199  ->  100 - 999
17200 - 18099  ->  100 - 999
18100 - 18999  ->  100 - 999
```

There are no doubt other ways to do it but it all depends on the desired distribution.

Answer (score 0):

For the problem you described, your solution is good enough.

`999` will appear 10 times more often than `1000`, though. If you want a smoother transition between the ranges, you could use :

```
# Defines a distribution for random numbers between min and max.
# Smaller numbers have a higher probably to appear.
class BiasedGenerator
  def initialize(min, max)
    @range = (Math.log(min)..Math.log(max))
  end

  def self.digit_range(min_digit, max_digit)
    new(10**(min_digit - 1), 10**max_digit - 1)
  end

  def rand
    Math.exp(Kernel.rand(@range)).round
  end
end
```

You just need to initialize it once :

`generator = BiasedGenerator.digit_range(3, 4)`

and use `generator.rand` as many times as you want :

```
random_numbers = (1..1_000_000).map do
  generator.rand
end

puts 'Min :'
puts random_numbers.min
puts 'Max :'
puts random_numbers.max
puts
random_numbers.group_by { |n| n.to_s.size }.sort_by(&:first).each do |digits, numbers|
  puts "#{digits} digits : #{numbers.size}"
end
```

it outputs :

```
Min :
100
Max :
9999

3 digits : 500061
4 digits : 499939
```

The distribution looks like this :
[image: Millions values with bias]

The green area between 100 and 999 should be almost the same as the one between 1000 and 9999.

Your generator also has this property :

[image]

For comparison, here is `Kernel.rand` :

[image]

With `BiasedGenerator.digit_range(3, 6)` :

```
Min :
100
Max :
999998

3 digits : 250342
4 digits : 250714
5 digits : 249814
6 digits : 249130
```